# Is there a way to view a list

Tags: r, list

When I have `data.frame` objects, I can simply do `View(df)`, and then I get to see the `data.frame` in a nice table (even if I can't see all of the rows, I still have an idea of what variables my data contains).

But when I have a `list` object, the same command does not work. And when the list is large, I have no idea what the list looks like.

I've tried `head(mylist)` but my console simply cannot display all of the information at once. What's an efficient way to look at a large list in R?

Comment: You can write a custom print method.

Comment: @JakubKania My RStudio console doesn't display the top of the list for some reason? I'm assuming my list is way too big (148MB)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use `str` to see the structure of any object, especially complex list's

Rstudio shows you the structure by clicking at the blue arrow in the data-window:

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Here's a few ways to look at a list:

Look at one element of a list:

```
myList[[1]]
```

Look at the head of one element of a list:

```
head(myList[[1]])
```

See the elements that are in a list neatly:

```
summary(myList)
```

See the structure of a list (more in depth):

```
str(myList)
```

Alternatively, as suggested above you could make a custom print method as such:

```
printList <- function(list) {

  for (item in 1:length(list)) {

    print(head(list[[item]]))

  }
}
```

The above will print out the head of each item in the list.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a package called [listviewer](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/4/14/week-15-listviewer)

```
library(listviewer)
jsonedit( myList )
```

Comment: This is the best way to get an overview. If you have large complex lists you can simplify with `rapply(x, class, how="list") %>% jsonedit`

Answer (score 10):

If you have a really large list, you can look at part of it using

```
str(myList, max.level=1)
```

(If you don't feel like typing out the second argument, it can be written as `max=1` since there are no other arguments that start with `max`.)

I do this often enough that I have an alias in my `.Rprofile` for it:

```
str1 <- function(x, ...) str(x, max.level=1, ...)
```

And a couple others that limit the printed output (see `example(str)` for an example of using `list.len`):

```
strl <- function(x, len=10L, ...) str(x, list.len=len, ...)  # lowercase L in the func name
str1l <- function(x, len=10L, ...) str(x, max.level=1, list.len=len, ...)
```

Comment: Great suggestion, imo.

Answer (score 5):

you can check the "head" of your dataframes using `lapply` family:

```
lapply(yourList, head)
```

which will return the "heads" of you list.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))
df2 <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))
dfs <- list(df1, df2)

lapply(dfs, head)
```

Returns:

```
> lapply(dfs, head)
[[1]]
          x         y
1 0.3149013 0.8418625
2 0.8807581 0.5048528
3 0.2490966 0.2373453

[[2]]
          x         y
1 0.4132597 0.5762428
2 0.0303704 0.3399696
3 0.9425158 0.5465939
```

Instead of "`head`" you can use any function related to the data.frames, i.e. `names`, `nrow`...

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as you explicitly specify that you want to use `View()` with a list, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
View(myList[[x]])
```

Where `x` is the number of the list element that you wish to view.

For example:

```
View(myList[[1]])
```

will show you the first element of the list in the standard `View()` format that you will be used to in RStudio.

If you know the name of the list item you wish to view, you can do this:

```
View(myList[["itemOne"]])
```

There are several other ways, but these will probably serve you best.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple edit of giraffehere's excellent answer.

For some lists it is convenient to only print the head of a subset of the nested objects, to print the name of the given slot above the output of head().

Arguments:

```
#'@param list a list object name
#'@param n an integer - the the objects within the list that you wish to print
#'@param hn an integer - the number of rows you wish head to print
```

USAGE: printList(mylist, n = 5, hn = 3)

```
printList <- function(list, n = length(list), hn = 6) {

  for (item in 1:n) {
    cat("\n", names(list[item]), ":\n")
    print(head(list[[item]], hn))

  }
}
```

For numeric lists, output may be more readable if the number of digits is limited to 3, eg:

```
printList <- function(list, n = length(list), hn = 6) {

  for (item in 1:n) {
    cat("\n", names(list[item]), ":\n")
    print(head(list[[item]], hn), digits = 3)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using as.matrix() on the list and then can use the standard View() command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and managed to solve it using `as_tibble()` on my list (dplyr or tibble packages), then just use `View()` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of RStudio, you can just use `View()` (or alternatively click on the little blue arrow beside the object in the Global Environment pane).

For example, if we create a list with:

```r
test_list <- list(
  iris,
  mtcars
)
```

Then either of the above methods will show you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`lobstr::tree()` is a great function for this - it prints a tree that shows the structure of list-like objects:

```r
library(lobstr)

my_list <- 
  list(
    "hello",
    list(
      c("some", "words", "here"),
      list(c(1:4), c(11:14)
      )
    ),
    list(
      list(
        list(10)
      )
    )
  )

tree(my_list)
#> <list>
#> ├─"hello"
#> ├─<list>
#> │ ├─<chr [3]>"some", "words", "here"
#> │ └─<list>
#> │   ├─<int [4]>1, 2, 3, 4
#> │   └─<int [4]>11, 12, 13, 14
#> └─<list>
#>   └─<list>
#>     └─<list>
#>       └─10
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-11 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>